# How to render dynamic array and update when data changed

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I want to render dynamic array and need automatic update when data changed.

I have a function that automatic generate 3 arrays every 3 seconds, my goal is to render 3 generated arrays and automatic update it every 3 seconds.

Here is my code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const response = new Array(4);

for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    response[i] = [];
}

class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { response };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.randData();
        setInterval(this.randData, 3000);
    }

    randData = () => {
        for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            (function (i) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    const arr = [];
                    const str = ['Boston','Florida','California','Alabama','Texas'];
                    const randStr = str[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)];
                    const randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
                    arr.push(i);
                    arr.push(randStr);
                    arr.push(randNum);
                    response[arr[0]] = arr;
                    console.log(arr);
                }, 200*i);
            })(i);
        }
    };

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.response);
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.response.map((item, i) => (
                    <p key={i}>{item}</p>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-v7m2raa?embed=1&file=index.js&hideExplorer=1)

From code above, i have a problem to render the array data.
If you try to run the demo at the link above, you can't see anything in the page. Just showing an empty page.

But if i inspect and look at the console then refresh the page, the `console.log(this.state.response);` showing the array data :
[image]

So i think the problem we can't see anything in the page is not because the array is empty and i think it have a different problem.

I need to render the array data and automatic update it when data changed.

Anyone can please help me to solve them?

Comment: updates doesn't affect the state, no reason to rerender

Comment: Use `setState` instead of assigning `response` state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some change in your code and it is working as expected. Notice calling `setState` function inside `randData`. `setState` re-renders your component with updated data (which is stored in the `state`).

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

const response = new Array(4);


class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { response };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.randData();
        setInterval(this.randData, 3000);
    }

    randData = () => {
        for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                    const arr = [];
                    const str = ['Boston','Florida','California','Alabama','Texas'];
                    const randStr = str[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)];
                    const randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
                    arr.push(i);
                    arr.push(randStr);
                    arr.push(randNum);
                    response[arr[0]] = arr;
                    this.setState({response})
                    console.log(arr);
                }, 200*i);
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.response.map((item, i) => (
                    <p key={i}>{item}</p>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: See the running example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-53468451)

Comment: Thank you very much saman.shahmohamadi, you solve my problem.
Thanks a lot.